# Is it possible to change only some part of decimal in mysql?

Tags: mysql, replace, int, decimal

I know it is kind of foolish question but is it possible to change only integer part of decimal value.e.g suppose I have number 12.34 then I want to change only 12 and .34 remain as it is.
I have two tables. table X and table Y

```
Table X 
id(int)|  value(decimal)
-------|--------
1      | 12.43
2      |  3.54
3      |102.07

Table Y
id(int)|  value(int)
-------|--------
1      | 32
2      | 76
3      | 8
```

I want to resultant table x like below

```
Table X 
id    |  value
------|--------
1     | 32.43
2     | 76.54
3     |  8.07
```

Replace int part of value of table X with value of table Y.
Is it possible in mysql?(with out any function call, something like string replace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To isolate the decimal portion of the values in the X table you may use the following expression:

```
X.value - FLOOR(X.value)
```

In other words, we can subtract off the whole number component.

```
SELECT
    x.id,
    y.value + x.value - FLOOR(x.value) AS value
FROM X x
INNER JOIN Y y
    ON x.id = y.id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Don't you want `FLOOR` instead of `ROUND`?

Comment: @RickJames Thanks.  Everyone's code has a smell, including mine.